# Change external svg to embedded svg

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have the following Code:

```html
<div style="height: 100%; width: 70%; margin-left: 15% !important;">
  <object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="test1.svg" class="img-responsive" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
</object>
</div>
```

which inserts an external svg in my html page.
Because I need to get access to every svg path by Id I need to do this with embedded svg. Right? But if I just copy and paste the svg code in my `object` tag I get a different result. But it should be the same. What do I need to change to get the same result? (Later the svg will be loaded with Ajax)

Link to svg file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z09mibjcwbikh3s/test1.svg?dl=0

Comment: Why do you not request the `svg` using ajax?

Comment: How is that svg file configured? Did you start with SVG for HTML? https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Comment: Like I said, later it will be loaded with ajax, but I think ajax does the same thing as I'm doing with copy and paste. So if the style is wrong with copy and paste I think ajax wouldn't fix that. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @daddygames What do you mean with "how is that svg file configured"? If you mean what the content of the svg is I posted a Link to Dropbox.

Comment: You don't need an embedded SVG, you can access the contents via the object tag if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean with `.contentDocument` ? I later need to add bootstrap popover to the position where I clicked. I think this is not possible via object tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear then because it contains no bootstrap popover code and therefore does not illustrate the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

The SVG code should not be put into the `object` tag, but completely replace it to form an inline SVG:

```html
<div style="height: 100%; width: 70%; margin-left: 15% !important;">
 <svg id="svg8" class="img-responsive" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="75.248mm" width="123.93mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 123.93211 75.24752">
  <defs id="defs2">
   <clipPath id="clipEmfPath1" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <path id="path10" d="m9.9116 3.8368h469.69v285.52h-469.69z"/>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(175.36 -102.89)">
   <g id="g139" transform="matrix(.26458 0 0 .26458 -178.17 101.73)">
    <path id="path16" d="m30.934 50.757v141.64h33.572v-141.64z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path18" d="m30.934 50.757h33.572v141.64h-33.572z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path20" d="m459.21 192.4v81.371h-428.28v-81.371z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path22" d="m459.21 192.4v81.371h-428.28v-81.371z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path24" d="m425.8 50.757v141.64h33.41v-141.64z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path26" d="m425.8 50.757h33.41v141.64h-33.41z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path28" d="m459.21 5.0358v45.721h-428.28v-45.721z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path30" d="m459.21 5.0358v45.721h-428.28v-45.721z" clip-path="url(#clipEmfPath1)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path32" d="m64.506 219.1v42.364h212.94v-42.364z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#4472c4"/>
    <path id="path34" d="m64.506 219.1h212.94v42.364h-212.94z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path36" d="m338.35 219.1v42.364h87.446v-42.364z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#4472c4"/>
    <path id="path38" d="m338.35 219.1h87.446v42.364h-87.446z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path40" d="m277.45 234.76v26.378h26.378v-26.378z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#000000"/>
    <path id="path42" d="m277.45 234.76h26.378v26.378h-26.378z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path44" d="m310.86 234.76v26.378h26.538v-26.378z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#000000"/>
    <path id="path46" d="m310.86 234.76h26.538v26.378h-26.538z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path48" d="m75.536 50.757v12.31h337.95v-12.31z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#7030a0"/>
    <path id="path50" d="m75.536 50.757h337.95v12.31h-337.95z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path52" d="m450.26 107.67v46.84h8.9524v-46.84z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#000000"/>
    <path id="path54" d="m450.26 107.67h8.9524v46.84h-8.9524z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path56" d="m30.294 107.67v46.84h8.7926v-46.84z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#000000"/>
    <path id="path58" d="m30.294 107.67h8.7926v46.84h-8.7926z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path60" d="m64.506 206.95v12.15h212.94v-12.15z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path62" d="m64.506 206.95h212.94v12.15h-212.94z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path64" d="m75.536 204.71v42.364h7.6735v-42.36z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#000000"/>
    <path id="path66" d="m75.536 204.71h7.6735v42.364h-7.6735z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path68" d="m338.35 206.95v12.15h87.446v-12.15z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path id="path70" d="m338.35 206.95h87.446v12.15h-87.446z" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="1.2789px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path72" d="m12.15 131.89c0 6.2747 5.0457 11.35 11.27 11.35 6.2247 0 11.27-5.0757 11.27-11.35 0-6.2647-5.0457-11.35-11.27-11.35-6.2247 0-11.27 5.0857-11.27 11.35z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#92d050"/>
    <path id="path74" d="m12.15 131.89c0 6.2747 5.0457 11.35 11.27 11.35 6.2247 0 11.27-5.0757 11.27-11.35 0-6.2647-5.0457-11.35-11.27-11.35-6.2247 0-11.27 5.0857-11.27 11.35" clip-path="url(#clipEmfPath1)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="3.0374px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path76" d="m454.82 133.01c0 6.2747 5.1157 11.35 11.35 11.35 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0757 11.35-11.35 0-6.2347-5.0757-11.35-11.35-11.35-6.2347 0-11.35 5.1157-11.35 11.35z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#92d050"/>
    <path id="path78" d="m454.82 133.01c0 6.2747 5.1157 11.35 11.35 11.35 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0757 11.35-11.35 0-6.2347-5.0757-11.35-11.35-11.35-6.2347 0-11.35 5.1157-11.35 11.35" clip-path="url(#clipEmfPath1)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="3.0374px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path80" d="m279.44 275.53c0 6.2347 5.0957 11.27 11.35 11.27 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0358 11.35-11.27 0-6.2148-5.0757-11.27-11.35-11.27-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0557-11.35 11.27z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#ff0000"/>
    <path id="path82" d="m279.44 275.53c0 6.2347 5.0957 11.27 11.35 11.27 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0358 11.35-11.27 0-6.2148-5.0757-11.27-11.35-11.27-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0557-11.35 11.27" clip-path="url(#clipEmfPath1)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="3.0374px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path84" d="m315.73 275.93c0 6.2747 5.0957 11.35 11.35 11.35 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0757 11.35-11.35 0-6.2547-5.0757-11.35-11.35-11.35-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0957-11.35 11.35z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#92d050"/>
    <path id="path86" d="m315.73 275.93c0 6.2747 5.0957 11.35 11.35 11.35 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0757 11.35-11.35 0-6.2547-5.0757-11.35-11.35-11.35-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0957-11.35 11.35" clip-path="url(#clipEmfPath1)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="3.0374px" fill="none"/>
    <path id="path88" d="m233.24 34.611c0 6.2347 5.0957 11.27 11.35 11.27 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0358 11.35-11.27 0-6.2148-5.0757-11.27-11.35-11.27-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0557-11.35 11.27z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#92d050"/>
    <path id="path90" d="m233.24 34.611c0 6.2347 5.0957 11.27 11.35 11.27 6.2747 0 11.35-5.0358 11.35-11.27 0-6.2148-5.0757-11.27-11.35-11.27-6.2547 0-11.35 5.0557-11.35 11.27" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="3.0374px" fill="none"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </svg>
</div>
```

The XML declaration that is usually present in SVG files, should then also be dropped.

The version in that snippet was cleaned up by saving as "Opimized SVG" in
Inkscape, which allows to automatically remove editor and metadata among other cleanup.